# Design Pattern or Best Practices for a thread spawing mutiple threads and ahead doing same till 3 levels

Tags: java, multithreading

I am looking for a better design pattern, or a best practice, to create a program, which has a thread spawned from main thread, and this thread ahead spawns multiple threads, and those thread spawns multiple threads ahead.

Main -> processes -> output used for a thread-level-1

thread-level-1 -> processes -> output used for a thread-level-2

thread-level-2 -> processes -> output used for a thread-level-3

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're doing that would even necessitate the threads.

Comment: I have a Utility, which waits for 1 threads output to start its process, the main threads output, suppose generates 4 URLs, the level-1 thread will process it, and call the different URLs in different thread, process its response, which may ahead have more 4 URLs, so level-2 threads will process it, and call these URLs to process, in level-3 threads. Hope you get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From your comment it seems like you have some kind of tasks that yield other tasks, but each task can be executed individually.*

Try using an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to submit `Runnable`s or `Callable`s to, depending on what suites you best. Within your tasks, you can then submit to the very same `ExecutorService`, without actually creating threads.

For the actual implementation, have a look at [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) - it will basically manage all the threading stuff for you.

Comment: thanks for the replay about executor service, I am aware of it, though, I was looking for a design pattern to be used in this approach. Well, lately I found, Chain Of Responsibilities pattern was appropriate here. Thank you very much for your help and time though.